# Find a weighted graph with $5$ vertices has exactly two minimal spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Draw a weighted graph with $5$ vertices has exactly two minimal spanning trees and justify that there are no other minimum spanning tree.

I could create a random graph which contain one minimal spanning tree but how to confirm it has another spanning tree?

[image: graph]

Like the above graph has one minimal spanning tree. Another confusion is what does it mean when they say **exactly two minimal spanning trees**? Does those spanning tree should have same minimum cost? If not then isn't the latter spanning tree could be more or less cost?

Comment: Hint: Start with a $5$-vertices weighted tree that looks like a cross (each edge should have a different weight). Then add $1$ more edge in a way so that it has $2$ minimum spanning trees (i.e. out of all the spanning trees, there're exactly $2$ spanning trees that have the same minimum total weight). To prove there're $2$ minimum spanning trees, try remove each of the edges. What do you observe?

Comment: **add 1 more edge in a way so that it has 2 minimum spanning trees** I tried to add edge at different nodes to the star graph but always end with $1$ spanning tree with minimum weight. How to sure two minimum spanning trees? @user900740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G = (V, E, w)$ be a weighted graph with $V = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\}$, $E = \{\{v_1, v_3\}, \{v_4, v_3\}, \{v_5, v_3\}, \{v_2, v_3\}, \{v_1, v_4\}\}$ and $$\begin{align}
w(\{v_1, v_3\}) &= 1 \\
w(\{v_4, v_3\}) &= 2 \\
w(\{v_5, v_3\}) &= 3 \\
w(\{v_2, v_3\}) &= 4 \\
w(\{v_1, v_4\}) &= 2
\end{align}$$
[image]
Then, it is easy to see $G$ has $3$ spanning trees by removing one of the $3$ edges $\{v_1, v_3\}, \{v_4, v_3\}, \{v_1, v_4\}$. Note that they have total weight $11, 10, 10$ respectively. Therefore, $G$ has exactly $2$ minimum spanning trees.

Comment: I see, I need to make sure two weight are same in order to make to spanning tree, isn't it? @user900740

Comment: @WhyGraph_ Yes, you need $2$ edges to have the same weight.